# Can you lose money in Vanguard money market settlement fund?

Tags: vanguard, money-market

Same as the title:

Can you lose money in Vanguard money market settlement fund?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible but very unlikely. Money market funds invest in high grade liquid assets and the primary goal is not to lose money. I have not been able to find an example of a Vanguard money market fund ever "breaking the buck" and having the value of a share go below a dollar. It is possible that this could happen in the event of a large scale financial collapse, but even then I would call it possible rather than likely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you **do** lose money in VMFXX, because that fund's yield is so much lower than the inflation rate.

(The loss is "hidden", but still real.)